# How to setup filtered access to youtube

Tags: ios, swift

Recently my app was rejected with cause: "The rating you have selected, 4+, is inconsistent with the content of your app. Since your app allows unfiltered access to YouTube, where content with mature or suggestive themes can be accessed, it should be rated 17+."

There are links from my app to youtube videos. I know some apps have links on youtube videos, but their rating less than 17+. I think there is way to tune filtered access, maybe by means of optional parameters in URL string, but I didn't find this in google api docs.

Do you know how it can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that indeed the app can show youtube in inapp browser (web view). The matter is that the app shows privacy policy page in inapp browser, and here are links to youtube videos. So, the rejection was justifiable. There were 2 options: to use other app, such as Safari to show privacy policy or leave inapp browser.

We choose to use inapp browser as previously, but implement filters for navigation by means of navigation delegate method:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void)
```

for example:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
        if let host = navigationAction.request.url?.host {
            if host.contains("www.yourhost.com") {
                decisionHandler(.allow)
                return
            }
        }

        decisionHandler(.cancel)
    }
```

Comment: did apple accept this solution?

Comment: how do you implement the filters when you use inapp browser? It is not very clear from your code. are you showing a privacy policy first?